Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions
I'm reading Classical Electrodynamics by Greiner. In the chapter about Green's function, the expression for potential $(2.18)$ is:

$$\phi(\mathbf{r}) = \int_V \rho(\mathbf{r}')G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}') \mathrm{d}V' + \frac{1}{4 \pi} \oint_S \left[G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}') \frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{r}')}{\partial n'}-\phi(\mathbf{r}')\frac{\partial G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')}{\partial n'}\right]\mathrm{d}a' \tag{2.18}$$

I'm confused as to why the boundary condition depends on $\mathbf{r}'$ $(\mathbf{r}'=\mathbf{r}'(S))$ instead of $r$ because the way I understand it is that $\mathbf{r}'$ is the position of the charge, which is being integrated, while $\mathbf{r}$ is the observation point, so it makes sense to me to say that the boundary condition should be $\phi (\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r} (S))$.
I would really appreciate any help.

The solution of Poisson's equation for the electrostatic potential depends on

the volume charge density $\rho$;
the values of the potential (or its normal derivative, but not both) on the volume's boundary.

As stated in this way, it should be clear that in the second term of the equation ($2.18$), the potential or its normal derivative on the surface should appear. Points on the surface have coordinate ${\bf r'}$.

But as the equation stated, the value of the potential only depend on r if given the surface being integrated(r' is no longer a variable since it's being integrated all over the surface and volume)

@user381761 The formula is crystalline clear. The value of the potential at any point $\bf r$ depends on the values of the potential at the surface (through an integration). If the potential on the surface is changed, the values of the potential at any other point will change.

Oh I think I get what you mean, thx a lot
